# Lowercase all strings in a list by list comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am confused on how my code is not turning all strings into lowercase?

```
def set_lowercase(strings):
    """ lower the case 2. """
    return [i.lower() for i in strings]


strings = ['Right', 'SAID', 'Fred']
set_lowercase(strings)
print(strings)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function builds a new list and returns it, but the calling code doesn't do anything with the returned value.

Answer (score 3):

You need to assign the result of your function call to the variable `strings`:

```
strings = set_lowercase(strings)
```

Answer (score 1):

`set_lowercase(strings)` doesn't modify the input in-place.
It returns a list of strings.

So, write `strings = set_lowercase(strings)` instead.